# How to use package laravel analytics?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I use package when I'm writing `view_id` in file `laravel-analytics.php`

This error appears

This is code test: 
[image]

This is Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file

```
config/laravel-analytics.php
```

You need to specify the view_id

```
/*
 * The view id of which you want to display data.
 */
'view_id' => env('ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID'),
```

Which you set in your **.env** file. Once you have done this you go to your project root folder and type in:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

If you go through the tutorial on the GitHub page - it has screenshots on how to retrieve the view_id

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#getting-the-view-id